# Salesforce: Bucket Fields

Tags: reporting

I want to create a report that summarizes contacts coming from data.com vs other. Can you create a bucket field on a report that shows 2 buckets:

Data.com bucket: Data.com Key != null 
Other: Data.com Key is null

Comment: did my answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I know, Bucketing is done based on the values of selected field. So, if `Data.com Key` is `null`, it cannot be defined as `Other`.

And most importantly, Bucketing is good when you have fixed or limited set of values (just like picklist) where based on picklist values you can define bucket values and `unbucketed` values will be mapped to `Other`. Here scenario doesn't fit for that.

You can define a formula (text) field like:

`IF(ISBLANK( Jigsaw),'Other','Data.com bucket')`

and use this formula field as `Group by` in `Summary` report.

For more information, refer this video: [Getting Started With Buckets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dq1TkYzT-mM)